# Css vertical navigation menu is overlapping

Tags: css, navigation, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make a vertical menu, with a submenu on hover. I want the submenu to appear directly below the hovered link, and to push the remaining menu elements below this submenu. How do I make the elements after the submenu to be pushed down after it, because with this code that I have it just displays the submenu in front of the remaining menu elements, making them not visible while the menu link is hovered.

It should look like this:

```
menu1
menu2
menu3
menu4
```

And on hover on menu2:

```
menu1
menu2
submenu1
submenu2
submenu3
submenu4
menu3
menu4
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="main_menu"><a href="#">Link1</a></div>
<div class="main_menu"><a href="#">Link2</a>
<div class="submenu">
<div class="submenu_link"><a href="#">Submenu1</a></div>
<div class="submenu_link"><a href="#">Submenu2</a></div>
<div class="submenu_link"><a href="#">Submenu3</a></div>
<div class="submenu_link"><a href="#">Submenu4</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main_menu"><a href="#">Link3</a></div>
<div class="main_menu"><a href="#">Lin43</a></div>
</div>
```

And my css code:

```
div.menu {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    width:260px;
}

div.main_menu {
    height:50px;
    padding:12px 0 0 12px;
}

div.main_menu a {
     display:block;
     height:32px;
     padding-top:2px;
}

div.submenu {
    display:none;
}

div.main_menu:hover div.submenu {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

div.submenu_link {
    position: relative;
    height:35px;
    padding:4px 0 0 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove height from this class

```
div.main_menu {
    /* height: 50px; */
    padding:12px 0 0 12px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ax97d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a few things to you 'div.main_menu' in CSS

```
div.main_menu {
//height:50px; /* remove */
padding:12px 0 0 12px;
overflow: auto; /* new */
display: block; /* new */
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2bEZF/